# Deleted file reappers in the File browser

Tags: android, android-file, android-download-manager

When downloading a pdf file using DownloadManager, I want to delete it if it already exists in `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`.

I check if file exists and delete it using these code:

```
private boolean fileExists(String fileName) {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
            fileName);
    return file.exists();
}

private boolean removeFile(String fileName) {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
            fileName);
    return file.delete();
}
```

removeFile() says that file is deleted, by returning true, and when I look  into File Browser only one file is showing up. But when I delete that file  it reappers on top of old one. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not wrong the `File file= new File(...)` will be your problem.

Because you are using the File class constructor, which is creates a new file to the exact location (File class documentation is here [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html)).

Try to give your `removeFile(String)`method a `File` type variable, that should do the trick (or use some File 'getting' method from the documentation).